# Not enough space left while upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade ubuntu but while upgrading it shows space not available in root. I tried to clean it using auto clean and removed some applications but still not able to make enough space. Can someone tell me how can i clean more space or can i increase this partition space?

The result of `df -h` is:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           383M  1.2M  382M   1% /run
/dev/sda6        12G   11G  391M  97% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  124M  1.8G   7% /run/shm
none            100M   52K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda8        93G   63G   26G  72% /home
/dev/sda1       496M   52M  445M  11% /boot/efi
```

[image]

Comment: What are the actual error messages?

Comment: Not enough free disk space

The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 3,855 M free space on disk '/'. Please free at least an additional 3,452 M of disk space on '/'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean

Comment: this is the message i am getting.

Comment: How is your system partitioned? One big partition or do you have a separate /home, /tmp, and /var ? Run `sudo fisk -l` to see the partitioning, and `df -h` to see exactly how much space is available in each partition, post the results.

Comment: sudo fisk -l is showing comand not found.    I have updated the post with result of df -h command.

Comment: Your problem is that your / partition on /dev/sda6 is too small. Edit your question to include a current-window-only screenshot of gparted, and I'll take a look.

Comment: please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

In my case usual solution is to remove old kernels - instructions may be found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/153193/609098